# Is there a way to stop an infinite loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to reach a process that combines
one hundred lists of eight different random numbers from a range of 1 to 50 numbers in interval three seconds each lists of one hundred.

The problem is the loop doesn't stop and it runs infinitely.

```
import random
import time
list_num = range(1,50)
round = 0    
while round <= 3:
     time.sleep(3)
     for list_comb in range(100):
         if round == 3: break
         else:
            list_comb = (random.sample(list_num,8))
             print(list_comb)
             round =+1
```

Comment: Why use a `while` loop? Typically, one uses a `while` loop when the number of iterations required for some task is unknown beforehand. Change your outer loop to a `for _ in range(3)`.

Comment: Unless you know what you're doing, don't use `round` as it is a [Python's builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Comment: It's not super clear what your desired end result is... do you want 300 samples of 8 numbers from `[1, 50)`? Do you mean to include 50 in the sample range? Why are you using `time.sleep()`? Do you intend to accumulate these samples, or just print them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the `while` loop is inappropriate here. The `for` loop is what you use when you want to repeat an action a specific number of times.

```py
import random
import time


for _ in range(3):
    for _ in range(100):
        random.sample(range(1, 50), k=8)  # do something with the sample
    time.sleep(3)
```

Also as mentioned, `round` is the name of a built-in function. Using it as a variable name overwrites the function.

Comment: Thank you very much, it´is even another shorter and efficient way to do what i´am expect from this exercise...

Comment: @Oldbit-RD glad I could help. Make sure to mark my answer as accepted if you are satisfied!